# Excel VBA API Query with variables not working - Expression.SyntaxError: Token ',' expected

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm using an API query connection in Excel VBA that uses a SQL statement to pull table data from a website but the SQL statement uses variables input by the user on the sheet. I've got the string generating the correct data but it's generating this error whenever I put the variables in instead of the hard-coded URL. I've searched for help but nothing seems to be working for me. I'm self taught and have no formal education in coding so please be patient with me and my questions and thank you in advance for any help and suggestions.

PowerQuery:

```
= let
Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents(""http://appwright.bldr.com/awapi/awapi.asp?user=xxxxxx.xxxxx&pw=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&cmd=awsql&fmt=xml&sql=Select Distinct TableOL2ID,key1,key2,key3,key4,key5,returnvalue1,returnvalue2,returnvalue3 from AMTDPSCREENVALS Where tablename='Install Pay Schedules' and TableOL2ID ='System'order by TableOL2ID"",
    Table0 = Source{0}[Table],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table0,{{"TableOL2ID", type text}, {"key1", type text}, {"key2", type text}, {"key3", type text}, {"key5", type text}, {"returnvalue1", type number}, {"returnvalue2", type number}}),
    #"Expanded key4" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Changed Type", "key4", {"Element:Text"}, {"Element:Text"}),
    #"Expanded returnvalue3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded key4", "returnvalue3", {"Element:Text"}, {"Element:Text.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded returnvalue3",{{"TableOL2ID", "Location"}, {"key1", "Customer"}, {"key2", "Install Type"}, {"key3", "Option Type"}, {"Element:Text", "Plan/Model"}, {"key5", "Option"}, {"returnvalue1", "Job Price"}, {"returnvalue2", "Sub Pay"}, {"Element:Text.1", "Quantity"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Excel/VBA code:

```
sourcexml = "Source = Xml.Tables("
source = "Web.Contents(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & APIURL & APISQL_DL & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(44)
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="SubPaySchedule", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & sourcexml & source & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table0 = Source{0}" & _
        "[Table]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table0,{{""TableOL2ID"", type text}, {""key1"", type text}, {""key2"", type text}, {""key3"", type text}, {""key5"", type text}, {""returnvalue1"", type number}, {""returnvalue2"", type number}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded key4"" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#""Changed Type"", ""key4"", {""Element:Text""}, {""Element:" & _
        "Text""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded returnvalue3"" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#""Expanded key4"", ""returnvalue3"", {""Element:Text""}, {""Element:Text.1""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns"" = Table.RenameColumns(#""Expanded returnvalue3"",{{""TableOL2ID"", ""Location""}, {""key1"", ""Customer""}, {""key2"", ""Install Type""}, {""key3"", ""Option Type""}, {""Element:Text"", ""Plan/" & _
        "Model""}, {""key5"", ""Option""}, {""returnvalue1"", ""Job Price""}, {""returnvalue2"", ""Sub Pay""}, {""Element:Text.1"", ""Quantity""}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns"""
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=SubPaySchedule;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$7")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [SubPaySchedule]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "SubPaySchedule"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

I tried placing the source power query code in a variable itself in VBA per a help site I found but it still doesn't work for me. I'm at a loss.

This is the error I get currently in the PowerQuery:

[image]

I've updated the power query code to include the closing bracket that was pointed out and I'm now getting a new error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCAjW.png)

Comment: Try switching `Web.Contents(""http:` to `Web.Contents("http:` (and at the other end of the URL also)

Comment: You could try storing the M code in a worksheet cell, instead of having to deal with managing all those escapes and concatenations in VBA.  You could also store it in a text file and read it in from there. Put placeholders in the M code for the variable parts, and use `Replace()` to swap in the actual values.

Comment: No luck on removing the set of double quotes on the URL - Thank you!

Comment: If you copy and paste your posted Powerquery M code into a worksheet cell and then use something like `ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="SubPaySchedule", Formula:=Thisworkbook.Worksheets("source").Range("A1").Value` does it work? (where for example your M-code is in A1 on sheet "source")

Comment: Looks like you are missing the closing brackets for `Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("...")),`

Comment: It now produces a new error message for me - I'll edit the post and add a screenshot of the new message